# if row contains specific text then build average google apps scripts (google sheets) (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I dont know how to program a code in google sheets wether in the sheet or in the script-tool using google apps scripts.

Example:

```
January 2017|February 2017|March 2017|April 2017|...
----------
Numberscolumn |Numberscolumn|

----------
```

I want to build a Average only of columns that have the word "January" oder "April" for example. How can I put the right code ?

Example:

```
=IF(TRUE;SEARCH("January "&" =ISNUMBER"; A2:A20))
```

Or maybe write an Macro in Google Apps Scripts ?

Comment: I'm not clear if January 2017 etc. are column headers or part of the data? Can you fill in a few more values plz?

Comment: January 2017 are column headers and not part of the data. The numbers under the months are part of the data. I want just build an average of numbers, if certain words are contained in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

If the headers are text rather than actual dates, this should work for you

```
=average(filter(transpose(A2:F),regexmatch(transpose(A1:F1),"January|April")))
```

[image]
If they are actual dates, then

```
=average(filter(transpose(A2:F),(transpose(A1:F1)=datevalue("January 2017"))+(transpose(A1:F1)=datevalue("April 2017"))))
```

Or to match on month and not specify a year

```
=AVERAGE(filter(transpose(A2:F),(text(transpose(A1:F1),"MMMM")="January")+(text(transpose(A1:F1),"MMMM")="April")))
```

Or more concisely

```
=AVERAGE(filter(transpose(A2:F),regexmatch(text(transpose(A1:F1),"MMMM"),"January|April")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work. I dont know why. The headers are Text. Under the headers (Months from january to December) I've got arround 28 numbers in the column, so that I want to build average of some months (for example only of January or April) , if the words "January" and "April" are in the headers row.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a link to your sheet or some dummy data?